# Error while importing Google drive example project

Tags: android, google-drive-api

---

I am trying to download and read h file from Google drive for this i have downloaded this example:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

### While importing project i got several errors. Below are screen shots.

[image]
[image][image]
[image]
[image]

---

### After importing libs manually same errors exists:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could run the sample code without a problem.

According to your images, it must be the references in your project that are causing issues.

Have you checked on the following links to correctly link the libraries? 
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

This might also help to smoothly run the sample code:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: play services library is imported successfully i think. Just imported the project imported play services lib project and added to   example project as seen in screenshots i don't know what is going wrong and i think its the correct way to import project.

Comment: i think the problem is with eclipse version.